# How to create performance listener for MyBatis statements

Tags: java, performance, listener, mybatis, ibatis

I would like to create a sort of Quality of Service for MyBatis statements, a sort of global performance listener which will analyze all executed MyBatis statements and log those that return too many hits or take too long. If possible in such a way that the impact on the existing business logic is as small as possible.

Comment: I don't think MyBatis supports execution listeners or metrics. Maybe you can add your own implementation on the mapper level.

Answer (score 1):

I only did a quick test, but a custom interceptor (a.k.a. plugin) like the following should do the job.

The message is logged only when 1) the log level is DEBUG or finer and 2) the execution time exceeds the value of the constant `THRESHOLD_NANOS`.

```java
import java.text.MessageFormat;

import org.apache.ibatis.executor.Executor;
import org.apache.ibatis.logging.Log;
import org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Interceptor;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Intercepts;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Signature;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.ResultHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.RowBounds;

@Intercepts({
  @Signature(
      type = Executor.class,
      method = "update",
      args = { MappedStatement.class, Object.class }),
  @Signature(
      type = Executor.class,
      method = "query",
      args = { MappedStatement.class, Object.class,
        RowBounds.class, ResultHandler.class })
})
public class LogExecutionTimeInterceptor implements Interceptor {

  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LogExecutionTimeInterceptor.class);

  private static final long THRESHOLD_NANOS = 0L;

  @Override
  public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    long before = System.nanoTime();
    Object result = invocation.proceed();
    long duration = System.nanoTime() - before;

    if (duration > THRESHOLD_NANOS && log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      MappedStatement mappedStatement = (MappedStatement) invocation.getArgs()[0];
      log.debug(MessageFormat.format(
          "Statement {0} took {1} nano seconds", mappedStatement.getId(), duration));
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

To register the interceptor...

1. with XML configuration

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin
      interceptor="xxx.yyy.LogExecutionTimeInterceptor" />
</plugins>
```

2. with [mybatis-spring-boot-starter](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/)

```java
@Bean
Interceptor getLogExecutionTimeInterceptor() {
  return new LogExecutionTimeInterceptor();
}
```

Comment: Hi @ave, I'm working on writing an open source class to stat the performance of the MyBatis queries in the database. Can I use the code in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create implementation of Interceptor interface and register it as a plugin in configuration file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).